# MySQL high CPU usage myisam

Tags: mysql, performance, cpu, myisam

Mysql CPU high usage (80%-150%). This is shop (10 000 products), max 15 online.

my.cnf

http://pastebin.com/xJNuWTWT

log mysqltunner:

http://pastebin.com/HxWwucE2

console:

[image]

Comment: So, What is the problem ?

Comment: HIGH CPU USAGE is problem. CPU > 100% is normal? 15 person online? Shop slow working... Please check my config. Thx

Comment: I would like to say you probably want to turn off persistent connections as they almost always do more harm than good. I am checking you .cnf now.

Comment: We have NO idea what the MySQL DB is doing from the information provided. How do you expect us to identify the problem? Maybe your queries are badly organised, missing indexes, not caching appropriately... who knows?

Comment: is what data do you need?

Answer (score 1):

Firstly

Some other things you can check would be to run the following query while the CPU load is high:

```
SHOW PROCESSLIST;
```

I can suggest you to turn off the persistant connections.

And then to check the MySQL users, just to make sure it's not possible for anyone to be connecting from a remote server

And at the same time I would like to say you want to turn on the [MySQL Slow Query Log](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/slow-query-log.html) to keep an eye on any queries that are taking a long time, and use that to make sure you don't have any queries locking up key tables for too long.

**http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/slow-query-log.html**

Kindly get over here too :

http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/memory-use.html

Comment: log for show processlist (root): http://pastebin.com/Jb5BMyuG

I have SLOW LOG. I want check config mysql and after change slow queries

Comment: Kindly get over here too http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/memory-use.html

Comment: I find, you processlist is normal and .cnf is good. Is your system too slow in processing queries ?

Comment: Read mysqltunner: [OK] Maximum possible memory usage: 2.3G (38% of installed RAM) AND ss form phpmyadmin: http://i.imgur.com/Xk1RvUG.png

Comment: I guess everything is normal. And at the same time Machine are the only responsible for this. If you have a large database and more connected users you should probably have a highly good configured machine.

Comment: I have 2 shop active and 5 shops clone. I must repair queries?

Comment: The best your optimize your query, the best you'l get result.

Comment: Thank for the help. help me with queries? I have ONE queries SLOW (repeats)

Comment: You are welcome. If my Answer helps you. Kindly mark it as answered (Ticket Button). Yes i can help you with query optimization.

Comment: This is slow query: http://pastebin.com/RNW0vgJX

Answer (score 1):

MySQL is only one part of the performance problem. Mysql only is not dedicated to high load traffic website or high load data website. You should find cache solution to deal with your problem. 10000 products is sufficiently large to slow down your website especially if there is no cache, if the server is not a dedicated server but with standard virtual hosting, etc.

To summarize, you should re-build the hardware architecture to take in consideration large database, user perfomance, dynamic pages.

Comment: VPS CLOUD (https://www.ovh.pl/vps/vps-cloud.xml number 4).
Cache for categories and manufacturer... Slow queries is form categories (25 products in one page)

Comment: You can check your mysql query logs to optimize your queries. I just give you tips but performance depends on a lot of factor. One among them is mysql, another one is the cms you use. Some cms consumes more than others.

Comment: this is slow query(repeated) http://pastebin.com/RNW0vgJX

Comment: The query is indeed complicated. For example, the selection WHERE (1=1 ) AND `active`= '1' AND `prod_cat` NOT IN (3841, 3840, 3845, 3837, 3700, 3828, 3827, 3821, 3846, 3819, 3842, 3843, 3847, 3788, 3838) is not well optimized.

Comment: Do you know how I can repeair this query?

Comment: For example, do not use WHERE (1=1). You can also split your mysql query in little part. CASE WHEN `products`.`price_prom` < `products`.`price` should be treated using php, not with mysql. But all of these depend on the content management system you used, is it possible to change them, and so on... I have no exact answer to optimize your website.